# Vertices not moving at all

Tags: modeling, mesh, error

[image]

My vertices refuse to move, but it lets me select it. No clue whats wrong, any advice?

Comment: If you look at the bottom status bar you'll see that the animation player is running. Press SPACE to stop it.

Comment: Thank you, this solved it!

Comment: I leave the marker on the timeline just visible at the bottom of the screen which makes it easy to spot if you've hit SPACE by mistake!